# Move the logic into new action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the some component. This component contains method "componentWillReceiveProps".
This method contains roughly the logic:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.someObject.obj1.prop1 != nextProps.someObject.obj1.prop1
      || this.props.someObject.obj2.prop2 != nextProps.someObject.obj2.prop2) {
      this.props.doAction1(nextProps.someObject);     
    }
    //any code
  }
```

the "this.props.doAction1" - is action.

Is it ok if I create the new action and moving this logic into new action?

For example:

```
function newAction(current, new){
    if (current.obj1.prop1 != new.obj1.prop1
      || current.obj2.prop2 != new.obj2.prop2) {
      doAction1(new);     
    }
}
```

And modify the componentWillReceiveProps:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {    
    this.props.newAction(this.props.someObject, nextProps.someObject);
    //any code
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `doAction1` is a redux action creator you **cannot** call it without wrapping it with a `dispatch`. Calling `doAction1(...)` directly won't trigger your reducer.

Presumably you've used `mapDispatchToProps` to receive `doAction1` as props to your component, so can invoke it like this: `this.props.doAction1(...)`. That is, `this.props.doAction1` is essentially a `dispatch` wrapped `doAction1`.

So if what I understand is correct you want something like this:

a method to do the comparison and dipatch your action as a callback

```
// the 'newAction' method
function checkAndDispatch(current, new, callback){
  if (current.obj1.prop1 != new.obj1.prop1
    || current.obj2.prop2 != new.obj2.prop2) {
    callback(new);     
  }
}
```

and inside your component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {    
  checkAndDispatch(this.props.someObject, nextProps.someObject, this.props.doAction1);
  // ...
}
```

---

**Points to ponder:**

- In Redux action creators are functions which `return` an object with a `type` key. The `type` is the target reducer.
- To trigger the target reducer, action creator should be wrapped with a dispatch when it is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

So what you've written is correct if you want to send both newAction and doAction1 as props to the component.
From your code, I think it might be better if you define 'newAction' as your component's function.
Just define it inside your component and bind it. It should be invoked as 'this.newAction'
You can also bind it to your component like this:

```
newAction = (current, new)=>{
if (current.obj1.prop1 != new.obj1.prop1
  || current.obj2.prop2 != new.obj2.prop2) {
  doAction1(new);     
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you're using term `action` in a wrong way. Action should provoke the update of reducers. Not a component logic, so it should be a method of the component or just a function if you want.
2. If you really mean action — don't use it in componentWillReceiveProps (this is the wrong pattern at all). In this case, you're risking to get

   - a recursive updating of app
   - mess in the state logic
   - inconsistent state
3. So if you want to provoke state updating (call reducer) if some objects have been changed (by reducer) — you'd better do it in the reducer (if that objects updating in other reducers — you can use redux-thunk / redux-saga). Also, it's better to call only one action for all these changes, to ensure consistency of the state.

**Summary:**

Actions should provoke atomic updates of the state. If you're composing a lot of reducers that don't know about other objects that you want to change — use `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga`, prepare data for reducers and call only one action, that should be used in a few reducers.

Don't move a logic of updating state into components (this is the same that you're using MVC and updating your Model from View).